# ¿Cómo reducir el peso en una aplicación IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

He desarrollado una aplicación para iOS con Objective-C, pero es muy pesada. ¿Qué tipo de cosas puedo hacer que reduzcan el tamaño de mi app?

En particular quiero mejorar en estos dos aspectos:

- Imágenes
- Reducción de código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno para las imagenes puedes hacer 3 cosas:

1) utilizar las 3 resoluciones @1X @2X @3X dependiendo del telefono el compila la resolución que necesite.

2) Utilizar sprites como en los juegos, de esta manera tu cargas una sola imagen png que contiene muchas de tus imagenes, esta imagen viene acompañada por un archivo XML o JSON que identifica en que coordenadas se encuentra cada una de las imagenes que componen la imagen.

3) Tener las imagenes en la nube y definir en la aplicación cuando sea pertinente comenzar con la descarga de ellas, en este caso puedes tenerlas comprimidas en una carpeta Zip, una vez las descargues las descomprimes y las guardas en local.

Para Reducir el codigo existen las arquitecturas de software, generalmente la mas comun y usada es el Modelo Vista Controlador pero existen otras como la arquitectura clean Modelo Vista Presentador. Personalmente lo que yo hago para ahorrar codigo es Tener una clase de constantes como colores, urls y parametros que no van a cambiar. Crear extensiones para muchas clases como NSString con validaciones de formatos como correos, numeros de telefonicos, etc. mantener la arquitectura en cada vista creando un XIB, un ViewController(NameClass) y un Modelo(NameClass). si requiero de una logica de negocio especial en el controlador entonces creo la clase BusinessLogic(NameClass) o si quiero conectarme a internet para algún proceso o varios procesos de la misma clase entonces creo la clase Repository(NameClass).

Espero esto te ayude un poco. (y)